# What is the correct way to handle validation errors in Ember when rollbackAttributes() leave the record unusable

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I suppose I naively thought that when a user fills out a form that fails to save and the server returns `422 Unprocessable Entity` I could just use `rollbackAttributes()` and let the user put in new values and try again.

Unfortunately, `rollbackAttributes()` seems the leave the record in state `root.deleted.saved` which makes it unusable.

More discussion [here](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/4209). I was getting the discussed problem, `Attempted to handle event 'didSetProperty' on [...] while in state root.deleted.saved`.

What is the point of rolling back if the record is unuseable? What is the correct way to handle this?

Thanks!

**Update:**

As to why I'm doing this in the first place, I have a form that updates every time a field is changed, and so it's fairly obvious to the user what field was invalid, namely the one just edited. Meanwhile, I have a generic save event that doesn't bother to know what field was edited, and so rather than display nice contextual validation errors next to each relevant field depending on what error occurred, I was being lazy and just rolling back so the person could try entering a new value. It was easiest just to roll back so I wouldn't need to figure out what had changed.

But as pointed out in the comments, maybe the problem is I am not distinguishing between unsaved and saved records.

Comment: Calling rollback on an unsaved model will delete it why would you try to rollback on validation error?

Comment: @Kitler, maybe I'm not distinguishing between unsaved and saved models. So is rolling back okay on saved models?